# how put home on the right side of navbar in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

put home on the right side of navbar then product and other menu items but with the folowing code it shows them in reverse order that i need

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" >
<div>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top " role="navigation" >
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=" .navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand navbar-right" href="Index.aspx"><span>
                    <img alt="Logo" src="Image/weather.png" height="30" /></span>Company name</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse " >
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"  >         

                     <li class="active navbar-nav "><a href="Index.aspx">home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">products</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">contacts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">users</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to achieve is this--
Just reverse the `<li >` order

**code snippet**

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
           <style type="text/css">
            
           </style>
           </head>
           <body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server" >
<div>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top " role="navigation" >
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=" .navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand navbar-right" href="Index.aspx"><span>
                    <img alt="Logo" src="Image/weather.png" height="30" /></span>Company name</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse " >
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"  >         

                     
                   
                    
                    <li><a href="#">users</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">contacts</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">products</a></li>
                    <li class="active navbar-nav "><a href="Index.aspx">home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
  </html>
```

Comment: No, it is not my desire, because in this order home went to the  most down part of the menu in small view. but I want to see it at top

Comment: i couldn't understand..can you explain what do you need actually?

Comment: your suggestion is true when the page is large and menu item display next together . but when user resize the page and menu display in a button menu (with three horizontal line) home comes to the bottom of dropdown menu instead of top